# Numerical integration formula

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a numerical method/scheme which can be used to solve the following equation

$$
\int_{t_n}^{t_n+h} \sin\left((t_n+h-s)\omega\right) g\left(x(s)\right)ds = \frac{1}{2\omega} \sin^2(h \omega) g_n
$$

Where $g_n$ stands for the function $g$, evaluated in the point $t_n$. I already tried using euler, implicit midpoint rule, but none of these standard schemes seems to do the trick.

Comment: What is known, and what are you solving for?

Comment: I'm studying a lecture on exponential integrators and the combination with some filter functions (Gautschi, Hairer & Lubich,...). Now trying to write out the equations and finding the origin of these so called filter functions. (The above equation is the last step I'm at)